# Using Twilio SMS I want to send a multi-segment message but tell Twilio where to break the message

Tags: twilio

I want to send SMS messages greater than 160 characters (say 240) and normally Twilio willl auto-segment as necessary.  I would like to tell Twilio where to break the messages (say three segments of 80 each).  We want to be sure the each segment arrives to the destination in the correct order and with logical message breaks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to programmatically handle the segmentation yourself. A SMS message over a certain length (based on [GSM7](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-gsm-7-character-encoding) or [UCS2](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-ucs-2-character-encoding) encoding) will be automatically handled. If you want to send 3 separate segments of 80 bytes, make 3 separate API requests overtime which will show up as 3 separate SMS messages on the mobile terminated device.

[Does Twilio support concatenated SMS messages or messages over 160 characters?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181508-Does-Twilio-support-concatenated-SMS-messages-or-messages-over-160-characters-)